# All my python windows services stopped working

Tags: python, windows-services, windows-xp

I run several python scripts as Windows Services on Windows XP. Just now they all died. They will not restart. I have no clue what is going on. I can't seem to get an error message to give me more insight. I haven't tried to reinstall any modules yet. What Modules are used by Windows Services in python?

EDIT:

When I reinstall pywin32 I do get this error:

[image]

However after clicking the 'ok' button, module does continue to install

Comment: Need more info. Did you try checking services.msc?

Comment: currently reinstalling pywin32... I will give update if that has any effect

Comment: reinstall of pywin32 had no effect

Comment: Weird. Did windows firewall block python or anything related somehow (grabbing at straws here)

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I did check services.msc. When I tried to start any of the services they crash right away. Strange thing is that in event viewer it does not even show that the service started in the first place as it normally did. This is true for all services that I had coded in python

Comment: See if there was a system software update. Then google to check if those software updates have compatibility issues with the modules you're using, specifically pywin32

Comment: Hmmm. I have windows update turned off right now.. I do have avg virus scanner running but I can't see anything in the logs for that...

Comment: Restart into safe mode and see if you can get the service running there. If so, then you'll know that it's one of the "unsafe" threads that's messing with your services

Comment: @inspectorG4dget see my answer below, I found the issue :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the Issue. Windows Error Log was full... So the script could not even send a message to log saying that service restarted thus it would fail and not log any error messages to boot.

Comment: That is one EPIC error. Kudos for solving it. But how did you actually figure out that that was the error?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I noticed that no new messages were being inserted into the log :)